# Subtract timespan.min from timespan.today

Tags: c#

I have a datatable column type TimeSpan. how would you subtract the Min of this timespan column from current time ? Appreciated.
Column name "Hours"

Comment: Please be more specific on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Calculate the minimum value :

   ```
   var min = table.AsEnumerable()
                  .Min(r => r.Field<TimeSpan>("Hours"));
   ```
2. Subtract it from current time:

   ```
   var newTime = DateTime.Now - min;
   ```

Comment: I can't use AsEnumerable! do I missing a reference ?

Comment: @user3216067 Yes - `System.Data` in `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`

Comment: hmm, I already have System.Data

Comment: You may need to add a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`. If you aren't using a version of .NET that has that assembly then you can just loop through the rows and calculate the min the old-fashioned way.

Comment: I got sequence contains no elements. and this because I have no data in table right now. my datatable generate data every minute and sometimes will be none. so how to avoid this ? thanks

Comment: "How do I avoid "sequence contains no elements" - Check for an empty sequence using `Any()` first.